# Rails form not working after link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

When I click on a link and move to a new page, my form doesn't submit.

It works normally if I refresh though. It also works normally after disabling Turbolinks.

How can I resolve this and keep using Turbolinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jquery.turobolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) sorted out a similar issue i was having. Just make sure you include it directly after jquery.

It just makes all your js bindings etc still work with turbolinks

Comment: Thanks. I did this in a previous project and it did work. Just found it weird that it's happening again and I wanted to see if there's anyone else is doing anything else about it.